# Kotlin: set focus to other edittext field when 13 numbers are entered

Tags: android, kotlin

First, I want to say I am completely new at programming and Kotlin, I'm trying it for just 3 days now, and have no experience at all, just reading a bit about it.

I have an android device with a barcode scanner. I have made an activity with 2 edittext fields and a button. In the first edittextfield (etbc), I scan the barcode with the device, so there comes a 13 digit number in it. Next to this field I have another field, etqty, where I enter the quantity.

I'm trying to get the program to automatically set the focus to etqty, when the 13 digit number is entered in the first field.

I already tried with length, but I don't really get any result. How can I accomplish this, or do I have to use another method?

This is the code I have for now (keep in mind I'm absolutely new to this, so my code can be a bit weird and messy, but for now it does what I want it to do :-))

```
    package com.example.project016

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io .InputStreamReader
import android.widget.Toast
import android.app.Activity
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption

class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity () {

    override fun onCreate (savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState)
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main)
        val etbc = findViewById (R.id.etbc) as EditText
        val et1 = findViewById (R.id.et1) as EditText
        val etqty = findViewById (R.id.etqty) as EditText

        etbc.requestFocus()
        if(fileList().contains("notes.txt")) {
            try {
                val file = InputStreamReader(openFileInput("notes.txt"))
                val br = BufferedReader(file)
                var line = br.readLine()
                val all = StringBuilder()
                while (line != null) {
                    all.append(line + "\n")
                    line = br.readLine()
                }
                br.close()
                file.close()
                et1.setText(all)
            }
            catch (e:IOException) {
            }
        }

        val button1 = findViewById (R.id.button1) as Button
        button1.setOnClickListener {
            try {
                val file = OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("notes.txt", Activity.MODE_APPEND))

                file.write (etbc.text.toString() + ";" + etqty.text.toString() + "\n")
                file.flush ()
                file.close ()
            } catch (e : IOException) {
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "data were recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           // finish ()
            etbc.getText().clear()
            etqty.getText().clear()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is to watch the text which is entered in the first field.

You could use `TextWatcher` for example:

```
        etbc.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if(etbc.text.length > 12) {
                    etqty.requestFocus()
                }
            }
        })
```

Give it a try. 
Btw. you could also set `android:maxLength="13"` in the xml